# How to make Mahout recommender work faster?

Tags: apache, hadoop, mahout

Hi Mahout community at SO!

I have couple of questions about speeding up recommendation calculations. On my server I have Mahout installed without Hadoop. Also jRuby is used for recommendation script. In the database I have 3k users and 100k items (270k items in join table). So when user requests recommendations the simple script starts working:

First it establishes db connection using `PGPoolingDataSource` like this:

```
  connection = org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource.new()
  connection.setDataSourceName("db_name");
  connection.setServerName("localhost")
  connection.setPortNumber(5432)
  connection.setDatabaseName("db_name")
  connection.setUser("mahout")
  connection.setPassword("password")
  connection.setMaxConnections(100)
  connection
```

I get this warning:

```
WARNING: You are not using ConnectionPoolDataSource. Make sure your DataSource pools connections to the database itself, or database performance will be severely reduced.
```

**Any ideas how to fix that?**

After it I create recommendations:

```
model = PostgreSQLJDBCDataModel.new(
    connection,
    'stars',
    'user_id',
    'repo_id',
    'preference',
    'created_at'
  )

  similarity = TanimotoCoefficientSimilarity.new(model)
  neighborhood = NearestNUserNeighborhood.new(5, similarity, model)
  recommender = GenericBooleanPrefUserBasedRecommender.new(model, neighborhood, similarity)
  recommendations = recommender.recommend user_id, 30
```

For now it takes about 5-10 seconds to generate recommendation for one user. The question is **how to make recommendations faster (200ms would be nice)?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know you are using a pooling data source, you can ignore the warning. It means the implementation does not implement the usual interface for pooling implementations, `ConnectionPoolDataSource`.

You're never going to make this run fast if trying to run directly off a database. There is just too much data access. Wrap the `JDBCDataModel` in `ReloadFromJDBCDataModel` and it will be cached in memory, which should work, literally, 100x faster.

Comment: Sean, I was hoping for your answer, thank you very much - ReloadFromJDBCDataModel was exactly what I needed. Without Reload it takes 8 seconds for a user and with reload I processed 119 users in 18 sec. It is 53x speed up!